# search for files not accessed for x days

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

How can I find files in Linux that were **not** accessed for X days?

I found that command, but it will show files that were viewed for the last x days:

```
$ find /home/you -iname "*.pdf" -atime -60 -type -f
```

Comment: What do you mean with accessed? Modified?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `-atime +60` to see files that have not been accessed within the last 60 days:

```
find /home/you -iname "*.pdf" -atime +60 -type f
```

Comment: Thanks! is it posible also to sort, lets say the "100 oldest accessed" files?

Comment: @rabotalius use -exec for that